# Temporarily disconnect from home Wi-Fi?

Tags: ios, wifi

On an iPhone, is there a way to temporarily disconnect from my home Wi-Fi *without* having to “Forget This Network”?

**Why I need this:**

- My home Wi-Fi sometimes has a very slow Internet connection.
- Meanwhile, my 4G always has a strong Internet connection.
- In those cases, I would like to:

  - disconnect my phone from my home Wi-Fi,
  - activate the phone's wireless hotspot,
  - use this hotspot to connect my PC to the Internet, via the 4G connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'll make my comment into an answer.*

For your particular situation, you don't need to temporarily disconnect from home Wi-Fi.

When you realise that the Wi-Fi doesn't work properly and you want to switch to 4G it's only necessary to start the personal hotspot from settings.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that the phone can both be a Wi-Fi hotspot *and* connect to my local Wi-Fi at the same time.

Comment: Kind of an elegant workaround for non-jailbroken devices to disassociate from WiFi short term while keeping the radio powered up - even if your goal isn't for anything to tether to the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable Wi-Fi temporary, by switching it off.

Comment: I can’t. I need the Wi-Fi.

Comment: You can click the other network you would like to connect to instead.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas this doesn't make sense!! If you disconnect from your home Wi-Fi you can't need it.

Comment: I don’t want to connect to another Wi-Fi network.

Comment: @Mattia I need the Wi-Fi to establish a wireless hotspot. I use 4G for the Internet connection.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas ok so, in this particular case. When you'll start an hotspot using Wi-Fi you'll automatically temporarily disconnect from my home Wi-Fi.

Comment: @Mattia Is that so? That would mean, when I connect my PC to the Internet via the phone's Wi-Fi hotspot, the phone's 4G connection is used, correct?

Comment: Yes right. For both the devices (iPhone and PC) the connection used will be your 4G. And your iPhone works as access point. This means that you can connect all the devices you want to the Wi-Fi hotspot generated from your phone as long there is battery and band.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32875/discussion-between-mattia-and-sime-vidas).